# Angular add class method as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function from a library which is called like this:

```
example: setMode(CLR.Drop);
```

**There are other options, Drop, Grab, None**

So, I've created a method:

```
selectMode(mode) {
    setMode(mode);
}
```

On a button click I've tried this:

```
<button (click)="CLR.Drop">Set Mode</button>
```

When I do the above I get that CLR.Drop is undefined.

So, I've having to pass a number or string like this:

```
<button (click)="selectMode('drop')">Set Mode</button>
```

And this have to do this:

```
selectMode(mode) {
    if (mode === 'Drop') {
        mode = CLR.Drop;
    } else if (mode === 'Grab') {
        mode = CLR.Grab;
    } else if (mode === 'None') {
        mode = CLR.None;
    }
    setMode(mode);
}
```

Is there a way to do this without end with lots of if's or a switch or is this the only way?

Comment: put `CLR` in a property of component (e.g. `CLR = CLR`) then your original code will work

Comment: HTML :
`<button (click)="selectMode('Drop')">Set Mode</button>`
TS : 
`selectMode(mode) {
    if (mode == 'Drop') {
        mode = CLR.Drop;
    } else if (mode == 'Grab') {
        mode = CLR.Grab;
    } else if (mode == 'None') {
        mode = CLR.None;
    }
    setMode(mode);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the property `CLR` to a local variable and pass it to the handler.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public clr = CLR;

  onClick(mode: any) {
    setMode(mode);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<button (mouseup)="onClick(clr.Drop)">Drop mode</button>
```

Or in the switch-case variant, send `'Drop'` instead of `'drop'`. String literal comparisons are case sensitive.

```html
<button (click)="selectMode('Drop')">Set Mode</button>
```

Comment: IDK, but giving type `any` just ruins the taste of TS. :/

Answer (score 0):

> Give the type of the parameter as the name of the member of the class. And assign the function to some method named variable. And call the method/

```
class Calc {

  add() {
    console.log('I am add');
  }

  subtract() {
    console.log('I am subtract');
  }

}


function CalcCaller(fun: keyof Calc ) {
const method = (new Calc())[fun];
  method();
}

CalcCaller('add');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=19#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYmNA3gKFdaYAm2AUAlChptMAPYB2E5IApgHQjkDmeA5AJJYC2Wu7AgG4SAX3SYIAVwBGAFwBOYYHMLFSZKjXpNWHbmD7T5SlYJGZxqK6gBmUyioCWVOAmDwQ9BXnuUAXNAA1nQAnuS2bojQRGgU1HLQPHRyABbk2NAAvNB4lHQA7lHAhAQA2n4AuhZJKen4wtbonh4I3hw42OZAA)